# iPhone/OpenAL getting sound length (playback time) of a sample

Tags: iphone, openal

I'm new to OpenAL. I managed to get a soundmanager code that wraps OpenAL for iPhone, so I can load sounds and play them.

But I really need to know how long each sound file is in seconds because I need to call an event as soon as the sound as finished.

I've noticed that there is a way to calculate the length of a sound when populating the buffers(?). Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
float result;
alGetSourcef(sourceID, AL_SEC_OFFSET, &result);
return result;
```

You can use this snippet to get the current playback time of the sound.

Answer (score 2):

If you are populating known size buffers with raw PCM audio samples of a known format, then:

```
duration = numberOfSampleFrames / sampleRate;
```

where, typically, the number of sample frames is the number_of_bytes/2 for mono 16-bit samples, or the number_of_bytes/4 for stereo, etc.

Comment: This is correct, and in the case of OpenAL, you'll ONLY be dealing with PCM audio, stereo or mono, 16-bit or 8-bit (although 8-bit doesn't seem to work on iOS).

Comment: My problem seems to be that without studying OpenAL, I won't know how to even get the size of the buffer or the sampleRate. It kills me that I do not have the time to study this yet. I'll look into it anyhow, and try to figure it out somehow. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Karl, that's not entirely true.  It is true for vanilla OpenAL, but with extensions it can also be other formats (such as 32-bit floating point).

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and came up with the following solution. The first function is optional, but allows to compensate for the elapsed time. I'm then firing an NSTimer with the resulting time interval.

Have fun! Dirk

```
static NSTimeInterval OPElapsedPlaybackTimeForSource(ALuint sourceID) {
    float result = 0.0;
    alGetSourcef(sourceID, AL_SEC_OFFSET, &result);
    return result;
}

static NSTimeInterval OPDurationFromSourceId(ALuint sourceID) {
    ALint bufferID, bufferSize, frequency, bitsPerSample, channels;
    alGetSourcei(sourceID, AL_BUFFER, &bufferID);
    alGetBufferi(bufferID, AL_SIZE, &bufferSize);
    alGetBufferi(bufferID, AL_FREQUENCY, &frequency);
    alGetBufferi(bufferID, AL_CHANNELS, &channels);    
    alGetBufferi(bufferID, AL_BITS, &bitsPerSample);    

    NSTimeInterval result = ((double)bufferSize)/(frequency*channels*(bitsPerSample/8));

    NSLog(@"duration in seconds %lf", result); 

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALint bufferID, bufferSize;
alGetSourcei(sourceID, AL_BUFFER, &bufferID);
alGetBufferi(bufferID, AL_SIZE, &bufferSize);

NSLog(@"time in seconds %f", (1.0*bufferSize)/(44100*2*2)); //44100 * 2 chanel * 2byte (16bit)
```