# CocosDenshion: why isPlaying always false (I can hear the music)?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, openal

I have this:

```
-(ALuint)ID
{ return self.soundSource->_sourceId; }

-(void)play
{
    [self.engine playSound:self.soundSource.soundId
             sourceGroupId:0
                     pitch:self.pitch
                       pan:1.0
                      gain:1.0
                      loop:NO];
}

-(NSTimeInterval)duration
{ return durationOfSourceId(self.ID); }

-(NSTimeInterval)offset
{ return elapsedTimeOfSourceId(self.ID); }

-(BOOL)isPlaying
{
    NSTimeInterval secondsRemaining = self.duration - self.offset;
    NSLog(@"<%.3f>", self.soundSource.durationInSeconds);
    NSLog(@"<%.3f> - <%.3f> = <%.3f> isPlaying <%i>", self.duration, self.offset, secondsRemaining, self.soundSource.isPlaying);
    return (secondsRemaining > 0.0);
}


#pragma mark - OpenAL addons

static NSTimeInterval elapsedTimeOfSourceId(ALuint sourceID)
{
    float result = 0.0;
    alGetSourcef(sourceID, AL_SEC_OFFSET, &result);
    return result;
}

static NSTimeInterval durationOfSourceId(ALuint sourceID)
{
    //Thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/a/8822347

    ALint bufferID, bufferSize, frequency, bitsPerSample, channels;
    alGetSourcei(sourceID, AL_BUFFER, &bufferID);
    alGetBufferi(bufferID, AL_SIZE, &bufferSize);
    alGetBufferi(bufferID, AL_FREQUENCY, &frequency);
    alGetBufferi(bufferID, AL_CHANNELS, &channels);
    alGetBufferi(bufferID, AL_BITS, &bitsPerSample);
    NSTimeInterval result = ((double)bufferSize)/(frequency*channels*(bitsPerSample/8));
    return result;
}
```

Where engine is just an instance of CDSoundEngine. I really want to know when will the music stop. I'm into it for a whole day now, and I'm tired.

It logs:
[1445:707] <1.656>
[1445:707] <1.656> - <0.000> = <1.656> isPlaying <0>

So the OpenAL source ID is right (since I can get the duration).
The CDSoundSource is also right (since I can get the duration from that as well).
I can hear the sound playing.

But AL_SEC_OFFSET is always 0.0, isPlaying is always NO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you get the state of the source and check if it is really being played?:

```
alGetSourcei(source, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &state);

return (state == AL_PLAYING);
```

Comment: Actually if I play it directly with OpenAL, then every of the approaches above just works well.

Comment: If I play the CDSoundSource with CDAudioEngine, or SimpleAudioEngine, then no any callbacks gets invoked.